# Как в Unreal Engine 4 сохранять игру указывая путь к файлу сохранений?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, сериализация, unreal-engine-4, save

Когда сохраняешь игру классом `SaveGame` в `blueprints`, ты не указываешь путь к файлу сохранения. Тогда вопрос: `"Как же сделать 2 сохранения игры?"`. Объясните мне как сохранять игру указывая путь к файлу сохранений. Можно на С++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы сохраняете игру через `SaveGame` требуется указать имя слота сохранения. Когда вы указываете существующее имя сохранения - оно перезаписывает предыдущее. Но вы можете указать разные имена для сохранений, и тогда файлы с разными именами будут независимыми друг от друга сохранениями. Путь к файлу не указывается, т.к. в папке с проектом/игрой создаётся папка `Saved` и в ней среди прочего есть папка `SaveGames` - туда и отправляются ваши сохранения.